# Jgroups nodes failed to add unique value to custom column of JGROUPSPING table

Tags: java, infinispan, distributed-caching, jgroups

Hope you all are doing well.

We are using Infinispan distributed caching using jgroups. The JDBC_PING protocol is used for registering and synchronizing nodes. We are adding one custom column (`node_name`) in jgroupsping table to uniquely identify each nodes. Here, it is expected that, each node should add unique identifier to custom column (unique identifier is the unique value set to environment property of each node).

But post nodes are registered to the JDBC_PING table, we see custom column value is same for all the nodes. Can anybody please let me know why this custom_column value is duplicated? Basically, first node value is used by all other nodes.

**create table sql : **

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jgroupsping (
   own_addr varchar(200) NOT NULL, 
   cluster_name varchar(200) NOT NULL, 
   ping_data varbinary(5000) DEFAULT NULL, 
   node_name varchar(50), 
   PRIMARY KEY (own_addr, cluster_name)) 
   DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"
```

**Jgroups-tcp.xml insert-sql :**

```
insert_single_sql="INSERT INTO JGROUPSPING (own_addr, cluster_name, ping_data, node_name) values (?, ?, ?,'${UNIQUE_NODE_NAME}' )"
```

**Files:**

**infinispan-configs.xml :**
[image]
**jgroups-tcp.xml :**
[image]

Thanks in advance,

jgroupsping table status post 2 nodes started in distributed mode:

[image]

Here, you can see same `node_name` is inserted for both the nodes even when nodes has unique value.

Why Jgroups does so? What is the way to insert unique value in node_name column of jgroupping table.

Comment: I've never used JDBC_PING but where does `JROUPS_NODE_NAME` come from? Is some environment variable set?

Comment: Yes, JGROUPS_NODE_NAME is a unique value which is set as environment property at each node.

Comment: Have you double-checked if it is unique? Did you try to attach a debugger to see what is the real query being executed?

Comment: Yes, I have cross checked, the JGROUPS_NODE_NAME is set with unique value at all the nodes. I have tried debugging JGROUPS_PING Class where it was seen with unique value set by the node. The main thing I have seen is, all other nodes jgroups use JGROUPS_NODE_NAME of first node which makes first entry in JGROUPSPING table.

Answer (score 0):

I can only support Pedro's answer: if you see unique values on the different members, then debug the insert_single_sql statement execution in all nodes. If the insert is successful, then the values must be unique.
Have you defined the other sql statements in JDBC_PING? e.g. select_all_ping_data?

Comment: No, I have not defined select_all_ping_data sql. Shall I test this with select_all_ping_data sql?